# For each WordPress page of my site why I have two URLs?

Tags: wordpress, url, permalinks

In my website, I set the custom structure permalink to "/post/%postname%". I want the URL of a single blog post like domain/post/postname and it is working fine but in addition to this every page of the website following both domain/post/pagename and domain/pagename URLs but for pages, I only want domain/pagename.

Both of these URLs landing on the same page

https://shergroup.com/aboutus
https://shergroup.com/post/aboutus

I only want https://shergroup.com/aboutus for pages.

Comment: In your custom structure use this only %postname%. This will work for you..
or you have to write custom script to hide post for pages.

Answer (score 0):

Change permalinks from setting to http://localhost/yoursitename/sample-post/
On pages, the simple posts will be changed to the page names.
And in your website, if you want to show a blog page like https://shergroup.com/aboutus/blog/ for that you need to change the slug of the web from /blogs/ to aboutus/blogs in a page but in my opinion, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Change Permalink common and optional settings (both), then you will get desired url structure.

Path :  Setting > Permalink